# Firefox 15.0 ignores meta charset="uft-8"

Tags: html, firefox

I have this simple html

```
<!Doctype html>
<head>
<title>Uft-8</title>
<meta charset="uft-8">
<style type="text/css">
.tr_deco{
background-color:pink;
border:1px solid red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a class="new_krud_slider" href="">make new</a>
</body>
</html>
```

When i try out the code on firefox 15,i get this firebug error.

> An unsupported character encoding was declared for the HTML document
>   using a meta tag. The declaration was ignored.

My firebug version is 1.7.3. What could be causing this error?.

Comment: Maybe it's time now to take a nap :)

Comment: @Chris I think this shouldn't have been closed as "too localized". The fact that my answer has 5 upvotes suggests that other people have made the same mistake of mis-typing `uft-8`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mate, you've mistyped `charset="uft-8"` (with the F before the T). Change it to `charset="utf-8"`:

```
<!Doctype html>
<head>
<title>Uft-8</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
.tr_deco{
background-color:pink;
border:1px solid red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a class="new_krud_slider" href="">make new</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Then it works fine. I know, I tested it my very self.

Edit: Now I realise you've typed `UFT` everywhere. The correct initialism is `UTF` ([UCS Transformation Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)).